# Dynamically add view in vertical and horizontal way

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create Buttons in `LinearLayout` dynamically, and I want to add those in vertical and horizontal way.

At first, add a `button A` in the layout, and if there's enough space between `button A` and screen edge, add `button B` to the right of `button A` (horizontally). Otherwise, add `button B` below `button A` (vertically).

My current layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

in class :

```
LinearLayout btnLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn_layout);
btnLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
for(Tag tag : tagList.getChildTags()) {
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setId(tag.getId());
    button.setText(tag.getName());
    btnLayout.addView(button);
}
```

In this case, if I set `orientation` as `horizontal`, then some of buttons are not showing (cut-off by screen), and if I set as `vertical`, it looks pretty bad.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this but not in a trivial way. I'll explain how I do something similar (in my case, I add `TextView`s) to `TableRow`s, if they fit.

With this approach you'll have to use a `TableLayout` and add `TableRow`s to it with your `Button`s. So you might replace your `"@+id/btn_layout"` `LinearLayout` to be a `TableLayout` instead.

Firstly, to get the screen's width, use something like this:

```
final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);

final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();

// Your screen's width will be stored within your params.width value
```

You'll use this to know if the current `Button` still fits the screen's width within the current `TableRow` or it has to be added to a new one. So now, use something like this to create your buttons:

```
int currentRowsWidth = 0;
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_table_layout);
TableRow currentRow = new TableRow();

for (Tag tag : tagList.getChildTags()) {
  Button button = new Button(this);
  button.setId(tag.getId());
  button.setText(tag.getName());

  // There's where you check whether it still fits the current `TableRow` or not
  if (currentRowsWidth + button.getWidth() < params.width) {
    currentRowsWidth += button.getWidth();
    currentRow.addView(button);
  }
  else {
    // It doesn't fit, add the currentRow to the table and start a new one
    tl.add(currentRow);
    currentRow = new TableRow();
    currentRow.addView(button);
    currentRowsWidth = button.getWidth();
  }
}
```

It might happen that once you get out of the loop there are still `Button`s to add in the `currentView`, simply test it:

```
if (currentRow.getChildCound() > 0)
  tl.add(currentRow);
```

I'm writing this from head, so some things might not compile at first time, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks nKn! Using `TableLayout` works very well, great answer!

Comment: @NariKimShin but button.getWidth() returns 0. how to fix this ?

Comment: @KetanAhir I guess you are creating `button` dynamically, and your width could be zero because it didn't draw the view yet. You can get width from GlobalLayout like : `button.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()`, and then `button.getWidth()` in `onGlobalLayout()`.

Comment: @NariKimShin yeah..I know that...but how can it work before adding button to layout(currentRow.addView(button);)